# How to enable Hidden buttons in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate an UI, The window have three buttons Submit, Edit, and Withdraw Buttons. When data is created manually All are three buttons are enabled. But when I run the scripts through automation using webdriver only Submit is enabled and the Edit and Withdraw buttons are hidden and not appear to perform the edit/withdraw operation.

Can anybody please suggest what needs to be done?

Please post in your suggestions as in how to enable the buttons and perform the operations? or any workaround methods.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for it. But the most common one is:

> Web now a days are full of ajax calls. So each field that your
>   referring may have an ajax call triggered, after you type the text. For example onChange event.

Selenium `sendKeys` won't trigger this. In order to get the proper response, you need to call the js function using `JavaScriptexecutor` which is responsible for triggering the events.

Comment: Thanks. How to use javascriptExcecutor
I tried using this code

WebDriver driver=null;

WebElement element =(WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementByLink('submit');");

element.click();

It is not working, Throwing null pointer exception.. How exactly do we need to pass arguments for Javascript Executor?

Comment: Your `driver` is `null`, so only your getting NPE